# Runtime Field Script emit null value for long

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-painless

I have a runtime field that converts a `long` field in milliseconds to seconds.  The problem is sometimes there is no value present in that row for the field.  To handle this, I added a check:

```json
PUT /my-logs-dev/_mapping

{
    "runtime": {
      "fields.Metric.ElapsedSeconds": {
        "type": "long",
        "script": {
          "source": "if(doc['fields.Metric.ElapsedMilliseconds'].length>0) 
                         emit(Math.round(doc['fields.Metric.ElapsedMilliseconds'].value / 1000d)); 
                     else
                         emit(0);"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

This works, but I would much prefer to emit "no value" to match the input. This way, when we aggregate in, say, dashboards, they row is simply ignored rather then diluting the aggregate value with zeros.  Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `emit()` doesn't support emitting `null`, you can simply remove the `else` section and nothing will be emitter if the field is missing

```
PUT /my-logs-dev/_mapping
{
    "runtime": {
      "fields.Metric.ElapsedSeconds": {
        "type": "long",
        "script": {
          "source": """if(doc['fields.Metric.ElapsedMilliseconds'].length>0) 
                         emit(Math.round(doc['fields.Metric.ElapsedMilliseconds'].value / 1000d));"""
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, the simplest things...thanks @Val.  I tried that but was receiving an error but now I realize it was for a different reason.